# Getting 'image_overlay_spec' to work Facebook Dynamic Ad Creative

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I'm trying to get 'image_overlay_spec' to work when creating Facebook Dynamic ADs. I've already gotten the templating for the actual ad itself to work, but I want to also be able to have info on top of the image.

```
    object_story_spec: JSON.stringify({
      page_id: process.env.FB_PAGE_ID,
      template_data: {
        description: '{{product.description}}',
        link: 'REDACTED',
        name: '{{product.name | titleize}}',
      },
    }),
    image_overlay_spec: JSON.stringify({
      text_template_tags: ['{{product.price}}'],
      text_type: 'price',
      theme_color: 'background_e50900_text_fffff',
    }),
```

This is what  I have right now. The object_story_spec works as expected, but the image_overlay_spec does not. The API doesn't have any concrete examples on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
    object_story_spec: JSON.stringify({
      page_id: process.env.FB_PAGE_ID,
      template_data: {
        description: '{{product.description}}',
        link: 'redacted',
        name: '{{product.name | titleize}}',
      },
      image_overlay_spec: JSON.stringify({
        overlay_template: 'pill_with_text',
        text_font: 'droid_serif_regular',
        text_type: 'price',
        position: 'top_right',
        theme_color: 'background_e50900_text_fffff',
        float_with_margin: 'true',
      }),
    }),
```